# Highlighting 2 separate parts using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight 2 spots on an image using mouse movement and clicking to confirm, first highlighting the 1st one, then the other. The problem I'm having is that once the first one is assigned, as soon as i move the mouse for the 2nd one, the first highlight still gets dragged along with the mouse pointer. How can I make the first highlight stay on the spot I left it in once I'm on the 2nd one?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    highlightiris('circle');
    setInterval(function(){
        if ($('#t_circle').val()=='') {
            $('#t_circle').val('in progess');
            highlightiris('circle');
        }
        if ($('#t_circle').val()=='done' && $('#t_circle1').val()=='') {
            $('#t_circle1').val('in progess');
            highlightiris('circle1');
        }
    },200);
});

function highlightiris(vara) {
    $('#'+vara).show();
    c_height = $('#'+vara).height();
    c_width = $('#'+vara).width();
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('#'+vara).css({top: e.pageY-(c_height/2), left: e.pageX-(c_width/2), position:'absolute'});
        $('#top_'+vara).val(e.pageY-(c_height/2));
        $('#left_'+vara).val(e.pageX-(c_width/2));
    });
    $(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        if (delta==1) {
            c_width+=2;
            c_height+=2;
            $('#'+vara).width(c_width).height(c_height);
        } else if (delta==-1) {
            c_width-=2;
            c_height-=2;
            $('#'+vara).width(c_width).height(c_height);
        }
        $('#dia_'+vara).val(c_width);
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
        $('#t_'+vara).val('done');
    });
    if ($('#t_'+vara).val()=='done') {
        return;
    }
}
```